# Inconveniente con la instalación de la herramienta Stack Builder de PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, postgresql-13

Cordial saludo.

Extiendo un cordial saludo desde Bogotá D.C, Por medio de la presente necesito solicitarles por favor me indiquen porque razón al momento de instalar el PostgreSQL,  no puedo instalar la herramienta StackBuilder , vale mencionar que utilizo el puerto  5432:

PostgreSQL 15(x64) on port 5432

Luego de realizar el mencionado proceso, me aparece un mensaje que dice:
Cheksum verification failed for: edb_pgbouncer.exe! Deleting file…
(¡La verificación de Cheksum falló para: edb_pgbouncer.exe! Eliminando archivo)

Fuera de que no se elimina este archivo automáticamente, no me deja continuar con la instalación.
Agradezco me indiquen que debo de realizar ya que no me deja instalar el gestor de base de datos
Las características de mi computador son las siguientes:

Sistema operativo: Windows 11 Home Single Language
Memoria RAM: 8 G.B
Procesador: AMD Ryzen de  2.10 GHz

Muchas gracias por la colaboración que me puedan brindar!.

Comment: "Cheksum verification failed" es un indicador de que el archivo está corrupto. Descárgalo de nuevo, de preferencia en una red estable. Muchos sitios de descarga tienen sha1 o md5 de la descarga para que puedas verificar tú mismo la integridad antes de ejecutarlo. Esto garantiza también que no hay infecciones de virus u otras alteraciones a los ejecutables.